# Efficient way of storing huge number of images in a NextJS project

Tags: next.js

I've been developing a NextJS project where I need to store image path of user profile pictures in the database.

Thus, my concern is can I store those images in /public/... and if I can, is it safe?

Also, if I store hundreds of images in /public/... will it affect the performance of my project in any way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with that, but Next JS is not created for this sake, and doesn't provide any static content related features like: optimization, caching, etc. In addition, it's not safe at all, and you need to implement authorization over the paths using custom server that decrease Next JS performance. My suggestion is using cloud storage.